# Is adding facebook analytics setUserID breaking relation to historic data?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk, facebook-analytics

We are logging events from our iOS app to facebook analytics already, but without `+setUserID:`. Now we want to identify this user to be able to connect the data to other services.

Is it possible to introduces the user identification with `+setUserID:` without breaking consistency and without loosing the connection to the history of the user?

(I am concerned that the new custom user id will be set only for new events, and the old events are not connected to the ones with the user id)

All links to official documentation that answers that question are welcome as a proof.

Answer (score 1):

No, setUserID will just add more information, but won't break the consistency of old data.

Comment: do you have any source for this statement?